# Geração de PDF GENEXUS

Tags: pdf, genexus

Galera sou desenvolvedora nova e estou aprendendo sobre Genexus.
Dai apareceu uma tarefa onde eu preciso pegar um gráfico que é gerado e colocar como opção gerar um PDF dele.
A linha de código esta assim ... Ele gera o arquivo na pagina de serviço e eu quero poder gerar um pdf partir dai

//Sample code for GoogleCharts
Sub 'LoadGoogleChartData'
&GoogleChartData.Categories.Add("2005")
&GoogleChartData.Categories.Add("2006")
&GoogleChartData.Categories.Add("2007")
&GoogleChartData.Categories.Add("2008")

```
&GoogleChartSeries = new()
&GoogleChartSeries.Name = "Sales"
&GoogleChartSeries.Values.Add(3045)
&GoogleChartSeries.Values.Add(4246)
&GoogleChartSeries.Values.Add(6537)
&GoogleChartSeries.Values.Add(2537)
&GoogleChartData.Series.Add(&GoogleChartSeries)

&GoogleChartSeries = new()
&GoogleChartSeries.Name = "Expenses"
&GoogleChartSeries.Values.Add(2045)
&GoogleChartSeries.Values.Add(3246)
&GoogleChartSeries.Values.Add(4537)
&GoogleChartSeries.Values.Add(5537)
&GoogleChartData.Series.Add(&GoogleChartSeries)
```

EndSub

//GoogleChartsControl event handler
Event GoogleCharts1.Select
msg(!"Selected Category Name: " + GoogleCharts1.SelectedCategoryName + !" Selected Series Name: " + GoogleCharts1.SelectedSeriesName + !" Selected Series Value: " + str(GoogleCharts1.SelectedSeriesValue))
EndEvent

Answer (score -4):

Então, pelo que eu entendi, você precisa adicionar uma opção para gerar um PDF a partir de um gráfico gerado em Genexus. A linha de código que você postou parece ser um exemplo de como carregar dados em um gráfico do Google, mas não está claro como isso está sendo exibido na página.

Para adicionar a opção de gerar um PDF, uma maneira de fazer isso é usar uma biblioteca de criação de PDFs em Genexus. Existem várias bibliotecas disponíveis, como a PDFSharp e a iTextSharp.

Uma vez que você tenha escolhido a biblioteca, você pode usar a linha de código que você postou para gerar o gráfico e, em seguida, usar a biblioteca para criar um arquivo PDF a partir dele. Você pode adicionar um botão ou link à sua página que, quando clicado, gera o PDF.

**Vou te dar um exemplo usando a biblioteca PDFSharp**

```
    // Importar a biblioteca PDFSharp
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Drawing.Layout;

// Código para gerar o gráfico do Google
// ...

// Cria um novo documento PDF
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

// Adiciona uma página ao documento
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

// Cria um objeto XGraphics a partir da página
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

// Cria um objeto XImage a partir do gráfico gerado
XImage image = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(GoogleCharts1.Chart);

// Desenha a imagem na página do PDF
gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, page.Width, page.Height);

// Salva o documento como um arquivo PDF
document.Save("grafico.pdf");
```

Nesse exemplo, a primeira coisa que fizemos foi importar a biblioteca PDFSharp. Depois, usamos o código que você postou para gerar o gráfico do Google. Daí, criamos um arquivo PDF novo e adicionamos uma página a ele. Aí criamos um objeto XGraphics a partir da página e um objeto XImage a partir do gráfico gerado. Por fim, desenhamos a imagem na página do PDF usando o método DrawImage e salvamos tudo no arquivo PDF com o método Save.

Só lembrando que você vai precisar adaptar o código pro seu aplicativo, dependendo de como o gráfico é gerado e mostrado na página, tá?

Comment: Importante entender a [finalidade do site](/help) para um melhor proveito da disposição em participar. Somos um repositório coletivo de conhecimento, não um helpdesk. Mais detalhes no link passado e respectivas páginas. Importante escolher postagens que estejam adequadas para o objetivo, e fazer respostas pontuais e objetivas sobre o núcleo do problema tratado, de forma que pergunta e resposta tenham problemas claros, fáceis de identificar e sirvam para um público amplo.